# Is there a package that can create signatures for Adobe pdf version 1.6 code?

Tags: pdf, adobe

We are having issues with Adobe ADS version `1040.20121017114537.881796` signing documents.  We can confirm that it can sign Adobe `pdf version 1.6` documents internally generated.  It cannot sign `eforms` or `digsig` documents.  These are `pdf version 1.5` documents.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Hope this is not off-topic for this site.

Is there any Latex package available than can create Adobe `pdf version 1.6` signature fields?

Minimal `digsig` sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{digsig} % <-- the driver is pdftex or xetex
\pdfminorversion=6
\begin{document}
  \digsigfield{5cm}{1cm}{test}
\end{document}
```

Minimal `eforms` sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eforms}
\pdfminorversion=6 
\begin{document}
  \sigField{test}{5cm}{1cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if you put `\pdfminorversion=6` in the preamble? Sometimes applications check the version number, but don't act on the information in any significant way, so simply telling the system that your file version is pdf 1.6 might solve the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that `%PDF-1.6` is produced for both packages.  Testing further...

Comment: I can confirm that `digsig` sample above is working and `eforms` not.  @Ian can you post your solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could only get the following `digsig` sample to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{digsig} % <-- the driver is pdftex or xetex
\pdfminorversion=6
\begin{document}
  \digsigfield{5cm}{1cm}{test}
\end{document}
```

I can also confirm that the following does not work with this specific version of  ADS:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{digsig} % <-- the driver is pdftex or xetex
\pdfminorversion=6
\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \digsigfield{5cm}{1cm}{test}
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

This specific version of ADS seems to be very buggy.

Comment: Neither of these allow me to sign the document produced.  Using adobe reader 9 on 14.04 Ubuntu.  Properties shows `"Signing: Not Allowed"`

Comment: I tried using the 2015 version of texlive.

Comment: As far a I know only `Adobe Reader 11.0.7` or later can sign documents.  All the samples work in `Reader 11.0.14.`  (I generated the pdf on SageMath Cloud by uploading `eforms` or `digsig`)

Comment: There seems to be provision in Linux Adobe Reader 9 for certificates, timestamps, and digital signatures.  It just seems that I produced a pdf that could not be signed (as per the properties dialogue).  I wish I knew what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Tried with 9.5.5 in Linux.  Cannot add signature to signature field.